# When we have two Realm DBs (one default (unencrypted) and other encrypted), will changes in one default DB schema impact other encrypted DBs

Tags: android, kotlin, realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-migration

DB1: default (unencrypted)
DB2: encrypted

Both are independent as they are completely individual DBs.

I'm using deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded() for both the DBs.

Now, suppose there is a schema change for a table in DB1 for migration purpose I'm using deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded() which tells that whenever there is a schema change in the DB, it will truncate the tables and reconstruct them.

I have made changes to the schema in DB1 and DB2 is unchanges.

Ideally , DB1 should truncate all its tables and recontruct them since there are schema changes and DB2 shouldn't truncate its tables since it is not affected by the schema changes of DB1.

But in my case, both the DBs are truncating their tables and reconstructing them. Ideally, only DB1(default) should truncate its tables but DB2 shouldn't.

I'm using @RealmClass annotation for both DBs data classes, does it have something to do with the problem I'm facing?

What might be the problem?

Comment: Good question. If you are not specifying which objects go with which Realm when opening the Realm, changing the schema of an object will fire off a migration event so you can handle version changes etc The weird thing I am seeing is that for my test, I had two Realm files, Realm1 and Realm2, and one object that appeared in both. When the schema was changed, it fired a migration event but the migration code only addresses one file Realm1, but, the migration was called twice and both files were updated to the new schema. So... I dunno. That's odd.